# can't get blender 3d model to show with proper lighting in javafx

Tags: javafx, blender

new to blender and java fx

I have a project for college in which I need to create a stupid 3d fruit and show it in java presentation with some transformations

I managed to create an apple in blender and exported form blender and into a javafx scene.
but no matter how the .obj is exported from blender, I can't get the object to show with proper lighting in my javafx application

this is how it shows in blender
[image]

and this is how it comes up with a pointlight shining right over in my javafx application

[image]

I checked this other related posting 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26088/obj-export-is-too-dark
but I couldn't make sense of what I need to change in blender.
by the way I'm using blender 2.8
any help is appreciated.

Update:

I added 2 more lights as per the 3 point lighting suggestion but I can't get the little green thingy at the top of the stupid apple to show green, it still comes up completely dark, what am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 3D world, the only light is what you put there.

One spotlight in your scene will light one side of your model, the other sides will be dark. Think of holding a torch under your face in the dark, you can't see the hand holding the torch or your shoulders, only your face that is right in front of the torch gets lit.

In blender you have environment lighting which is emitting light from all directions.

It is common in 3D to use [threee point lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-point_lighting) to clearly illuminate a model.

Comment: Hi samble. thank you for getting back. I've gone ahead added 2 more lights, but the green stick at the top of the 3d apple model still comes up completely dark.. what am I missing?

Comment: I would check the normals are facing outwards. In the viewport overlays menu, there is a face orientation option, turn it on, does the stem show as red? Select the stem in edit mode and press Shift-N or Ctrl-Shift-N so that it is not red.

Comment: I solved the stem problem by using map_Kd fruit_skin.png line along with the respective fruit_skin.png file to get the proper color to come up